# What could be the extreme of building logic inside an application(software) i.e. GMail Attachment Validation

Tags: java, .net, programming-languages, artificial-intelligence

I have recently visted the [GMail Blog](https://blog.google/products/gmail/), and found the **extreme point of logic building inside software**,

i.e.

> Never forget an attachment again
>
> Gmail looks for phrases in your email
>   that suggest you meant to attach a
>   file (things like "I've attached" or
>   "see attachment") and warns you if it
>   looks like you forgot to do so. Every
>   day, this saves tons of people the
>   embarrassment of having to send a
>   follow up email with the file actually
>   attached.

[image: gmail popup]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/S33Z-Q7yNUI/AAAAAAAAAfA/Aalj4Wvfk08/forgotten_attachment_warning.png))</sub>

**I think this is too much...**

Please share your expreience about the extreme point of logic building inside software/application.

Comment: Why do you think this is too much? It's helped me a number of times...

Comment: It's correct, But how much intelegince could be build over there.
i.e. if i wrote: I AM CALLING BACK, then shuld it show "PLEASE CALL"

Comment: How is this related to AI? It's simple pattern matching using strings. It's a neat feature - doesn't hurt or get in the way, so why not?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with any of the tags you've chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Google is writing *their* code for *their* application.

If the context were instead a public library for sending mail messages, then your argument of *"this is too much"* might have more weight. In that case, a better approach might be to provide a [hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_(programming)) where code can be installed that can check the text and attachments and issue a warning if something doesn't look right.

The *attached* / *not attached* issue is very common and this is a completely reasonable way for Google to handle it in Gmail.  Most likely it is in the same block of code that checks for empty messages and blank subject lines.